# How to get version 2.2 in visual studio for asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

Currently I am using `Visual studio 2017` and it that `asp.net core`. In that there is showing version `asp.net core 2.1`.

But this is not the latest version for using `asp.net core 2.1`. So how can I want to use in `asp.net core 2.2` in existing visual studio, which is `2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shorten Answer:

Suggest you using [official website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.2) to download ASP.NET Core SDKs and then run the downloaded file to install the SDK. Relaunch the Visual Studio and create a Web Application and then you'll find the ASP.NET Core 2.2.

---

From the [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/2.2/2.2.4/2.2.4.md?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website) said Visual Studio 2017 support sdk version is end with `SDK 2.2.106`. Begin with `SDK 2.2.203`, you need use Visual Studio 2019 version `16.0`. So Visual Studio 2017 does not support the latest version of ASP.NET Core 2.2. The latest version that Visual Studio 2017 can download is `2.2.106`(Runtime version is 2.2.4).

Besides, the official document does not **emphasize the Visual Studio 2017 specific version**, it is better to use the latest version. Because if the Visual Stuidio version does not match the SDK version, it will not display ASP.NET Core 2.2 when you create a web application.

For example:

For my 64-bit version of Windows, I will choose the following link to download the sdk:

[image]

**Note:**

ASP.NET Core current release version is `.NET 7 preview 1`, ASP.NET Core 2.2 is actually an old version.

Comment: Thanks Rena, sorry for delay as I was busy in some other things